# Browser cannot connect to tomcat running inside of VM

Tags: web-server, http, vmware-player

So,
i'm running a webserver inside of VM image (VMWare Player 5.0.1) on windows 7 SP1 64bit, and neither IE, nor Chrome load the page with the address of it: `http://192.168.201.128:8080`

BUT:

- `ping 192.168.201.128` works
- `telnet 192.168.201.128 8080` works, and i can `GET /` and see html response
- i can even proxy requests to it with Nginx, using `location / {  proxy_pass http://192.168.201.128:8080; }`, and that allows me to work around the issue.

p.s.: my colleagues run the same image in same player in same environment without any issues.

The question: **what can i do to fix it in a proper way** - to be able to connect directly to VM, without this hacks ?

---

*update 1:*

When looking at network inspection in Chrome, i see the 504 error:
`Remote Address: 172.XX.XX.XX:8080
Request URL:http://192.168.201.128:8080/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:504 Proxy Timeout ( The connection timed out.  )`

There are also suspicious headers in request: 
`Proxy-Authorization:Negotiate XXXLONGHASHORKEYSTRING...`
and in response `Via: XXX TMG` (looks like Forefront TMG)

Such headers only appear when i try to connect to IPs instead of URLS, just in case of success they are fine like with **google** (64.233.164.113), and in case there is some error (like attempting to connect to 8.8.8.8) i'm getting 504 as well.

Comment: What is the error indication from the Browser?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: probably this question should be moved to SuperUser, instead of ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Browsers are configured to use a proxy. To reach your local addresses, you need to disable the proxy setting.

Comment: indeed, my bad. Simply updating list of proxy exclusion addresses have helped.